# What filetypes can Crafter Search index?

Tags: crafter-cms

Crafter search can index attached files. For example, I can search the contents of an attached PDF...

However, is it compatible with Docx?
and image metadata? (for example jpg)
Is there a compatibility list somewhere?

I'm having issues getting docx and a jpg indexed, although a PDF is working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crafter Search relies on Solr that uses the Apache Tika library to index binary documents. You can find the list of compatible formats here: https://tika.apache.org/1.16/formats.html (for CrafterCMS 3.0) and https://tika.apache.org/1.5/formats.html (for CrafterCMS 2.x)

For proprietary formats such as docx you need to check the compatibility and the supported fields in the library documentation.